# module_param: display value in hex instead of decimal

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Is it possible to display value of module_param when read, in hex?

I have this code in my linux device driver:

```
module_param(num_in_hex, ulong, 0644)

$cat /sys/module/my_module/parameters/num_in_hex
1234512345
```

Would like to see that value in hex, instead of decimal. Or, should I use different way like debugfs for this?

Comment: Have you googled how to convert decimal to hex in Linux? A quick search yields [this](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/04/quick-hex-decimal-conversion-using-cli.html). Did you try it?

Comment: Debugfs has nothing to do with this. Decimal format is just how kernel prints integer module param. You need to convert this value to hex using Unix tools. Try to google for "linux convert decimal to hex".

Comment: Look for something like echo 'ibase=10;obase=16;1234' | bc

Answer (score 3):

There is no ready parameter `type` (2nd argument of `module_param` macro), which output its argument as hexadecimal. But it is not difficult to implement it.

Module parameters are driven by callback functions, which extract parameter's value from string and write parameter's value to string.

```
// Set hexadecimal parameter
int param_set_hex(const char *val, const struct kernel_param *kp)
{
    return kstrtoul(val, 16, (unsigned long*)kp->arg);
}
// Read hexadecimal parameter
int param_get_hex(char *buffer, const struct kernel_param *kp)
{
    return scnprintf(buffer, PAGE_SIZE, "%lx", *((unsigned long*)kp->arg));
}

// Combine operations together
const struct kernel_param_ops param_ops_hex = {
    .set = param_set_hex,
    .get = param_get_hex
}; 

/*
 * Macro for check type of variable, passed to `module_param`.
 * Just reuse already existed macro for `ulong` type.
 */
#define param_check_hex(name, p) param_check_ulong(name, p)

// Everything is ready for use `module_param` with new type.
module_param(num_in_hex, hex, 0644);
```

Check [include/linux/moduleparam.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h) for implementation `module_param` macro and [kernel/params.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/params.c) for implementation of operations for ready-made types (macro  STANDARD_PARAM_DEF).

Comment: It should be x8, x16, x32, and x64 to fullfit the support of all possible single types.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko: It is not difficult to generate callback functions for different size of parameters. Like `STANDARD_PARAM_DEF` macro does that for decimal input/output. Actualy, unlike to user-space libraries, **it is not needed to geralize all kernel functions**: only *required* functionality needs to be implemented.